# HQL convert complicated hql to criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

HQL

```
Query query = getSession()
        .createQuery(
                "select com from News as news " +
                "join news.comments as com " +
                "where news.id = :id " +
                "order by com.addDate desc"
        );
query.setParameter("id", id);
```

HQL above works fine. Want to change in the criteria api. I can not make. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can try something like this.

```
    Criteria c  = createCriteria(News.class);
    c.add(Restrictions.idEq(id));
    Criteria cComment = c.createCriteria("comments",c);
    cComment.addOrder(Order.desc("addDate"));
    ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList();
    projections.add(Projections.property("c.id"),"id");
    projections.add(Projections.property("c.addDate"),"addDate");
    //Other Properties...
    c.setProjection(projections)
    c.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Comment.class))
    List<News> list = c.list();
```

Please mind that the Hibernate Criteria API is being deprecated in favor of the JPA Criteria API

Comment: Your example is very good, but it returns list News. I want to return Сomments.

Comment: Oh Sorry. You Comment pojo have the reference to the News?